# injective function proof

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I've seen (in a book) a lot of proofs that some given function is injective, but I don't understand why this proof holds. One example of the proof is like this:

Given 2 functions: $f: X \rightarrow S$ and $g: X \rightarrow T$, the function $<f,g>\;: X \rightarrow S \times T$ is defined as $<f, g>(x) = (f(x), g(x))$.

Proof that $< f, g >$ is injective:

---

Suppose $< f, g > = < f', g'>$. Then for any $x ∈ X$,

$$(f(x), g(x)) \quad= \quad< f, g >(x) \quad=\quad < f', g' >(x) \quad=\quad (f'(x),g'(x))$$

The coordinates of these pairs must be the same, so $f(x) = f'(x)$ and $g(x) = g'(x)\; \forall x ∈ X$.

Hence $f = f'$ and $g = g'$, so $(f, g) =(f', g')$.

---

this didn't look like a proof to me... am I wrong? How can this argument prove that $< f, g >$ is injective?

Comment: This question, as is written does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: i fixed the mistakes

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's being shown is that the map taking $f$ and $g$ to $<f,g>$ - that is, the map $<\cdot,\cdot>$ - is injective. In other words, let $h(f, g) = <f,g>$, and we show that $h$ is an injection from $A \times B$ to $C$, where $A$ is the set of functions $X \to S$, $B$ is the set of functions $X \to T$, and $C$ is the set of functions $X \to S \times T$.

The proof supposes that $h(f,g) = h(f',g')$, and shows that it must be that $f = f'$ and $g = g'$; that's exactly what needs to be shown for injectivity.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason for the confusion is as follows.

You start by saying that you want to prove $\langle f,g\rangle$ is injective.  But what you are really showing is that the function
$$(f,g)\mapsto \langle f,g\rangle$$
is injective.  In other words, the function of interest has domain
$$\{\hbox{pairs of functions $f:X\to S$ and $g:X\to T$}\}$$
and codomain
$$\{\hbox{functions $h:X\to S\times T$}\}\ .$$